# web.py define /x to go to x.html in templates?

Tags: python, web.py

In web.py how can I define going for example to *example.com/x* to go to a file inside templates folder called *x.html*?

Very new to web.py and would like to know how to do this! Their documentation doesn't explain much of anything to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://webpy.org/cookbook/url_handling), you can do it like this:

```
urls = (
    '/(.+)', 'your_handler_class'
)

class your_handler_class:
    def GET(self, page):
        print web.template.render('%s.html' % page)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic URL handling in web.py.

For your example, do the following:

```
urls = (
    "/x", "x"
)
```

This assumes you have defined a directory for your templates and created that directory one level deep (or wherever), for example as follows:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/')
```

web.py will then look in the templates directory for x.html when you render the page, usually with a GET handler, as such:

```
class x:
    def GET(self):
        return render.x()
```

In this case, both your class and your template are named x, but this doesn't need to be the case.

For example, you could have named your template 'xyz.html' and called it with `return render.xyz()`, and still named your class 'x' and mapped it to /x

Answer (score 1):

Just use `getattr` passing it `render` and page name captured by url regexp.

```
urls = (
  '/(.+)?', 'PageController'
)

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class PageController:

    def GET(self, page='index'):
        try:
            return getattr(render, page)()
        except AttributeError:
            raise web.notfound()
```